# Background banners (skins) in responsive layout, how to implement them?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I am looking for tutorials, ideas, suggestions on **how to implement the "skin-banners" (also called background-banners) in responsive  template** as the famous *twitter bootstrap template*.

How to manage the width of the background picture? 
Is it possibile to implement a *backgroud banner without using javascript complex scripts?* **Are there any working examples?**

Many thanks, Fabio

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to display the correct skin for each viewport.

First of all you needto read the width of the window browser:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
var WidthBrowser = $(window).width();
</script>
```

Then for each viewport you have to call the right skin.
For desktop version for instance:

```
if (WidthBrowser > 1200){
// code for skin
}

else if ...
```